# @FetchRequest does not update on updates in another window

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a MacOS App, that allows to be stated in multiple Windows.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct TM_window_TestApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ItemListView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TM_window_Test")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}

extension Item {
  public var name: String
  { get
  { return name_ ?? "NONAME"
  }
    set(newName)
    { name_ = newName
      //objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }
  
}
```

I expect, that the windows work on the same ManagedObjextContext.

In the ItemListView() I list all the Items.
When adding a new new Item, it's only shown in the window, where the "plus" Button was pressed, not in the other windows.
(Interestingly on iPad in splitview it works as expected).
Why are the @FetchRequest in the other Windows not updated?
How can I force that update?

```
struct ItemListView: View {
  @StateObject var listProperties = ListProperties()
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
  @FetchRequest( sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)])
  
  private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List(items, id: \.self, selection: $listProperties.selectedItem ) { item in
        Text("\(item.name) at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
      }
      .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
          EditButton()
        }
#endif
        ToolbarItem {
          Button(action: addItem) {
            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
          }
        }
      }
      Button("Delete All Items"){deleteAllItems()}
    }
  }
  
  private func addItem() {
    let newItem = Item(context: moc)
    newItem.timestamp = Date()
    
    do {
      try moc.save()
      moc.refresh(newItem, mergeChanges: true)
    } catch {
      let nsError = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
  }
  
  private func deleteAllItems () {
    
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    
    deleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs
    do {
      let result = try moc.execute(deleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
      let changes: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSDeletedObjectsKey: result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] ?? []]
      NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [moc])
      
      
    } catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("DELETING ALL \("ITEM") failed: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .short
  formatter.timeStyle = .medium
  return formatter
}()
```

Comment: You don't have  a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but have you tried passing the `moc` as an `@EnvironmentObject` as well, and using that version in your view? `@Environment` won't trigger a refresh, but `@EnvironmentObject` will.

Comment: I added the PersistenceController and Item extension.  Is it a MRE now? Only the Datamodel is missing (how could I provide this?)

Comment: Is it possible to pass the moc as @EnvironmentObject? I think: NSManagedObjectContext does not conform to ObservableObject.

Comment: @Yrb Interestingly on iPad it works as expected.

Comment: Please make an effort to remove everything unnecessary just have the bare bones minimum reproducible code, make it easy for someone to quickly understand the problem.